# Returning minimum value for a ISODate value in a collection

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need to return the minimum client_timestamp value per user in a collection however the I have not been able to get the $min operator to function in this way. Is there a means of getting the query to return the minimum client_timestamp for all user_ids in the collection?

query = ???
db.collection.find(query).distinct("client_timestamp")

Example Document Structure:

```
{
  "device_type" : "Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2600 CPU @ 3.40GHz (8173 MB)",
  "user_id" : "17204977745451858462",
  "organization_id" : "1",
  "client_timestamp" : "2014-09-10T04:46:39.201Z",
  "client_session_id" : "PpfprJalFTNDZa2Ag1wUQ5D2Mfw",
  "_id" : "0de1611e-d835-4557-9948-cbbf88afa098"
}

{
  "device_type" : "Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2600 CPU @ 3.40GHz (8173 MB)",
  "user_id" : "17204977745451858462",
  "organization_id" : "1",
  "client_timestamp" : "2014-09-10T04:46:39.368Z",
  "client_session_id" : "PpfprJalFTNDZa2Ag1wUQ5D2Mfw",
  "_id" : "21e71acf-43e4-4a2d-b946-074fe7983034"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) is your answer for finding a minimum value. It has the [**`$min`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/min/) grouping operator which does exactly this in a [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) pipeline stage:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": None,
        "client_timestamp": { "$min": "$client_timestamp" }
    }}
])
```

Grouping is done by the value or combination of field values specified in `_id`, where any Null or empty value will group the entire collection.

Also see the [SQL to Aggregation mapping chart](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/) in the documentation for many common examples.